# C++: in while(cin) loop, sometimes the loop is ignored

Tags: c++

In my code, I tried to create a loop, but every once in a while the whole loop is ignored after it gets my input.

This is the loop:

```
while(std::cin >> word){
        std::cin.clear();

        qType = (rand()%2) + 1;
        letter = (rand()%26) + 1;
        if(qType == 1){
            std::cout << letter << std::endl;
        }else if(qType == 2){
            std::cout << Letters[letter] << std::endl;
        }
}
```

When I write my input, the first few times the loop successfully outputs either a letter, or its corresponding number, but shortly after, it stops doing so. I found people with similar problems, but for them the solution was to add a cin.clear(); function, which I added to the end first, and then the start, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: What is the type of `word`?

Comment: what's `Letters`? You don't need an array for getting letters. Just use `'a' + letter` or `'A' + letter`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc -- that code is not portable. Character codes are not required to be contiguous, and there are encodings for which they are not (EBCDIC being the prime example). That approach works for the digits `0` through `9` because they are required to be contiguous and increasing. For letters, converting through an array is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you didn't give a termination condition so maybe this code work for you...

```
while(word!="exit"){
    cin >> word;

    qType = (rand()%2) + 1;
    letter = (rand()%26) + 1;
    if(qType == 1){
        cout << letter << std::endl;
    }else if(qType == 2){
        cout << Letters[letter] << std::endl;
    }
            cin.clear();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what should be the end of you while loop? The way you have your loop set up, it will never end. Also you aren't using word variable nowhere inside your loop so what is the point of it. If you want to loop until the user inputs some exit code it should look like this:

```
std::string word;
while (word != "exit") {
    std::cin >> word;
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while(std::cin >> word && word != '\n'){
    std::cin.clear();

    qType = (rand()%2) + 1;
    letter = (rand()%26) + 1;
    if(qType == 1){
        std::cout << letter << std::endl;
    }else if(qType == 2){
        std::cout << Letters[letter] << std::endl;
    }
```

}